# laravel download file with ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to download the file by sending required parameters via ajax request.

I first stored the output file to `public/exports` directory and on `success callback` tried to redirect to that file path.

```
public function downloadResults() {
    /* get filter control inputs */        
    $inputParams = $this->request->input();
    .
    .
    .
    try {
        $exportArr = $this->product->downloadResults($filterArr); <-- this will store the file to public directory.
    } catch (\Exception $e) {        
        $jsonArr['success'] = false;
        $jsonArr['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        echo json_encode($jsonArr);
    }
    $jsonArr['success'] = true;
    $jsonArr['filename'] = $exportArr['file'];
    echo json_encode($jsonArr);
}
```

On callback,

```
$.ajax({
            data: filter_rules,
            url: "{{ @url("/dmf/download-results") }}",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(resp) {
                $("#overlay").hide();

                window.location.href = "{{ asset('public/exports/') }}" + '/' + resp.filename;
            }, 
        });
    }
```

It then redirects to `http://localhost:8000/public/exports/result_set_download_1589388303.xls` route which doesn't exist.

So how can I access that file now?

Comment: Is it button click download or page refresh download??

Comment: it's a button click download..button click initiates the ajax request with parameters.

Comment: You can download from controller and there is no page refresh on it

Comment: It sounds like you just don't have the path right?  `public/` should not appear in the URL.  [Have you set up your public disk etc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)?

Answer (score 0):

check out this package [downloadjs](https://github.com/rndme/download)

you can use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get the BLOB data from the server and download the blob using [downloadjs](https://github.com/rndme/download)